# Python 3 - how to write CSV rows to text files without truncating middle columns?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, text, truncated

I am loading a csv into a dataframe and writing each row of the dataframe to a separate text file using the following code:

```
b = pd.read_csv("my.csv", delimiter=',', encoding='UTF-8')  
b = b.replace(np.nan,'',regex=True)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

file = 'file{}.txt'
n = 0
for row in b.iterrows():
    with open(file.format(n), 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(row))
        n += 1
    f.close()
```

This works, except that the resulting text files have truncated columns with "..." in the middle. The columns are not being truncated in the actual dataframe, just the written files. I have already read through several similar issues but none are helping me fix this. Would appreciate any help you can give me!